# Compress HTML string containing embeded image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, compression, embedded-resource

I am trying to do a javascript app which uses local storage to store HTML data which occasionally contains embedded images.but the problem is here i am apposed to a size constraint.do you guys know of any javascript library to compress **HTML with embedded image**?
I have tried [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) but it fails with embedded image.any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably JPEG images that is embedded, right? You cannot compress the images any further anyway, so focus on the HTML. On desktop browsers you probably just have 10MB of local storage, so It's not the best solutions I'm afraid.

For HTML compression, I would also recommend lz-string.

Comment: I wouldn't compress the HTML though.... I think 10 MB (or 2MB for mobile) is enough HTML data for me :)

Comment: thanks for your response.i managed to solve problem by extracting images and storing them uncompressed into local storage giving them a GUID and setting GUID as src value.but you deserved an up vote for the answer.cheers!